# how to insert Chinese value in mssql using php

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$insert_val = "insert into [LightingDB].[dbo].[pendinglist] (  [Order_number]     ,[Name],[phone],[vendor_address],[vendor_name],[product],[gender],[birthday]      ,[order_date],[p_key_address],[payment_status]) values ($order_id,'$customer_name','$phone','$vendor_address','$vname','$product','$gender','$bdate','$order_date','$pkadr',$payment_status)";
```

This is work with english data but when i put chinese data in it, this is showing error as below:

> Warning: mssql_query(): message: Incorrect syntax near '77777777'.
>   (severity 15) on line 1068
>
> Warning: mssql_query(): General SQL Server error: Check messages from
>   the SQL Server (severity 15) in line 1068
>
> Warning: mssql_query(): Query failed line 1068

Answer (score 0):

My **guess**: it's the encoding. With "Chinese data" you want to say you are using the non-latin letters, right?

Did you check the collation of your database/table(s)? It must be `utf8_unicode_ci` for your database and your table(s).